# How to add registry entries while installing drivers

Tags: camera, driver, device, inf

I made some changes to my camera driver inf and added few registry entries under `[cameramodel_Device.AddReg]`  (this is after `[cameramodel_Service_Inst]` in the `inf` file).

But after installing this modified `inf`, I don't see the entries that added in the registry under camera GUID --> Device parameters.

Can anyone help me where I should add my entries in the `inf` to get the custom entries under Device parameters?

Comment: cpu-registers is probably not a relevant tag for _this_ discussion. You also don't say what operating system or tools you use to generate the installer. We can assume some kind of Windows, and you might be editing the raw INF file. But drivers, and driver installing is tricky for a reason. You will need to share more details.

Comment: agree that i shouldn't have added cpu-registers as a tag, just removed it.I am checking this on Win10 15063 version. i haven't used any tools to generate inf, i just modified the inf that i got and installed it by "disabling driver signature enforcement".  And, i want my changes in inf to come under HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\control\Deviceclasses

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Make sure you put details like those in your last comment in the _body_ of the question.